# Reload page out of iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, fancybox

I'm using Fancybox and Zend. Hope the following is clear.

On www.example.com/template/edit/id/3 I have jQuery UI Tabs. They are reachable directly via anchors. E.g. www.example.com/template/edit/id/3#tabs-2

On #tabs-2 I have some elements, doesn't matter what it is exactly. You can create or edit them. This elements got a own controller, so for editing them you call /elements/edit/id/44. Currently, I'm doing that in a Layer with Fancybox. I'm using the Iframe functionality of Fancybox for that.

So, if you are on /template/edit and you click on the edit button of an element, a layer opens which includes an iframe which loads /elements/edit.

So, if you change the element now and click on save, i want the layer to automatically close and reload.

Fancybox provides an option to specify what it should do when it gets closed. At the moment i got it like that:

```
'onClosed'          :  function() {window.location.reload();}
```

This actually reloads the top window and not the iframe. Also, there's a possibility to close Fancybox via JS. I'm doing that by setting a View Variable which triggers this, e.g:

```
<?php if($this->close): ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
    </script>
<?php endif ?>
```

So, if the saving was successfully I set $this->view->close = true and the layer gets clsoed which triggers my JS.

This works fine. My Problem now is to do the reloading with having #tabs-2 in my url.

Of course i could get the urls, clean it up from other anchors the user my typed in etc. and build my url which i set to the window's location, but somehow i think, there must be an easier solution.

E.g. setting the url of the browser to #tabs-2 without reloading, but this also sounds not very nice. The reloading is easy but having the anchor there is quite tricky.

Comment: Did you try `window.location.href = window.location.href`?

Comment: This would be the same as reload(). The reloading works actually but if you are on the second tab, edit something, save it, you want to stay on the second tab after the reload and not go back to the first. No anchor is by default the first tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.location.href = "#tabs-2"
```

Maybe:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    parent.$.fancybox.close();
    window.location.href = "#tabs-2" //Add the anchor, won't stack. Will replace existing anchor
    window.location.reload() //Refresh the screen, maintain anchor
</script>
```

Comment: Ends up in ../id/2#tabs-2#tabs-2#tabs-2 if he edits a few elements in a row. I probably have to check if windows.location.href contains #tabs-2 or 1 and handle it according to that

Comment: Make sure you're putting it as-is... no extra special logic should be needed. It really shouldn't stack like that

Comment: Anyway. It links me to element/edit/id/2#tabs-2 instead of template. I don't really get why. Alerting href at the onClosed gives me the correct path but if you make href = tabs2 then it goes to the element. Also window.top doesn't change anything.

Comment: Maybe try `window.location.hash = "#tabs-2"`

Comment: Seems like window.location.href = "#tabs-2"; window.location.reload(); has done the trick. Thanks, also works with .hash though.